# Excel - stuck on simple point

Tags: excel

I am really lost on below table somehow and couldn't find a way to get out. I need to input one value to a cell and other cell needs to check, apart its fractions to get the result in a singe cell.

Can you please look up and assist me on this matter ?

Here are the conditions:

```
If value between; price;

0 –      1000     100
1001 –   2000     145
2001 –   3000     170
3001 –   4000     200
4001 –   5000     230
5001 –   7500     280
7501 –  10000     320
10001 – 20000 per 1000NT or fraction thereof        15
20001 – 30000per 1000NT or fraction thereof         10
30001 – 40000per 1000NT or fraction thereof          5
40001 – 50000per 1000NT or fraction thereof          5
Over 50001additionalper 1000NT or fraction thereof   5
```

My solution so far:

```
I8 CELL = =IF(E11>=10000;320;)

J8 CELL = =ROUNDUP(SUM(E11;-10000)/1000;0)

J9 CELL = =IF(AND(ROUNDUP(SUM(E11;-10000)/1000;0)>=1;ROUNDUP(SUM(E11;-10000)/1000;0)<=10);J8*75)

J10 CELL = =IF(AND(J8>=11;J8<=20);J8*65)
```

[image]

Comment: What result do you expact for your example?

Comment: Why do you this this is _simple_? On the contrary it is not,

Comment: Have you considered vlookup() instead of nested if() ?